Renormalization of powers of the Gaussian free field
Let $h$ denote the Gaussian free field on $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ for $d\geq 2$. As $h$ is distribution valued, powers of $h$ are not well defined. However in dimension $d=2$ we know that we can mollify $h$ and renormalize $h$ through Wick powers. However the $d=3$ case I hear is more subtle.
Does anyone have a good reference for renormalization of powers of the GFF, particularly when $d=3$?

I assume that what is meant here is the construction of Wick powers $:h^k:$ as random distributions which are deterministic function(al)s of the underlying random distribution $h$ given by the GFF. For the $d=2$ case there, where the scaling dimension is $[h]=0$ and correlations diverge logarithmically on the diagonal,  I think there is a good account of that in the $P(\Phi)_2$ book by Barry Simon.
For $d>2$ and more general random distributions $h$, this is done in detail in my article
"A second-quantized Kolmogorov-Chentsov Theorem via the operator product expansion", Comm. Math. Phys. 376 (2020), no. 1, 555--608. The preprint version is here. The needed assumption is that $k[h]<d/2$, i.e., that $:h^k:$ is less singular than white noise. As far as I know giving a probabilistic meaning to the Wick powers when $k[h]\ge d/2$ is an open problem, even when one is right at the borderline case as for the energy field of the Ising model in $d=2$.
BTW, I asked a related question here: Squaring random Schwartz distributions

Quick question, what is $[h]$ in dimension $d$? Thank you for your answer, this is helpful.
